# ASP.net API get call returns controller class, not data

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, extjs, sencha-architect

I've created an API in ASP.net. My Sencha SPA is attempting to get data from it. Unfortunately the get call is returning the controller class rather than the data I want. Any ideas?

Here is the get method:

```
private firstAPIContext db = new firstAPIContext();

    // GET: api/AccountModels
    public IQueryable<Account> GetAccountModels()
    {
        return db.Accounts;
    }

    // GET: api/AccountModels/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Account))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccountModel(string username)
    {
        Account accountModel = await db.Accounts.FindAsync(username);
        if (accountModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(accountModel);
    }
```

Here is the rest proxy code from Sencha:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.AccountsStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.AccountModel',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Rest'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            storeId: 'AccountsStore',
            model: 'MyApp.model.AccountModel',
            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                url: '/Controllers/AccountsController.cs'
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you have added a JSON Reader on your Sencha Store.So that you can read the response send by the server.Also make sure that you are sending JSON data back from the server for this add the following lines in you Global.axpx

```
 var config=GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
 config.Formatters.Clear();
 config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

And also change the url to like this
 **url: '/Controllers/AccountsController/'**

This seems to be the main reason for me because you have added an extension 
**.cs** thats why when u call the method it returns the whole controller class instead of the data.Try to remove this extension too and do all what i have suggest.Hope it will works fine